# RapidApi Testing returns `kutz-log-nil-tenantid`

Tags: rapidapi

On RapidAPI I have created a new API and added a simple GET endpoint (`/version`). Every call (from the Dashboard Test Endpoint feature and from the browser) returns

```
{"version":"kutz-log-nil-tenantid"}
```

Anyone experiencing the same? Did I miss some configuration? I cannot see what it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `/version` is a reserved word and cannot be used.
After creating a different endpoint (ie `/status`) it works fine.

RapidAPI [documentation](https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/endpoints#create-an-api-endpoint) lists the reserved words but `version` in not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I think something was wrong from the backend when you were creating this endpoint because `/version` is not the reserved word.

It should work fine if you try this now.

Remember, you can always write to the RapidAPI support team(support@rapidapi.com). They are very active and would love to help you out.

Comment: Thanks Pratham. I contacted Support and they confirmed it is a reserved word but the documentation is not up-to-date. They are working (apparently) to fix this.